# how to write a asynchronous content provider in android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-contentprovider

i'm writing a content provider that provides search results for other applications.The content provider sends requests to server and parse response.now it can work successfully without asynchronous calls.but if i want a asynchronous content provider,that is,creating a thread in the query() function.and then comes the problem,how can i know when the thread is finished and has got the results.because now i just new a Thread,and start it,however,the cursor could not get results.anybody can help me?Thank you!

Comment: You could use a CursorLoader to achieve this. You can find the concept explained here: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Answer (score 1):

My application has this same problem.  Depending on your situation, you may be able to return an empty cursor from your query call, and then have your views update when the cursor's data is updated.  If it makes sense with your data source, you can subclass MatrixCursor (or another cursor) and make sure to call onChange when the cursor's data is updated after the asynchronous request completes - this should notify that cursor's observers of the new data, and then they can show it.

Comment: Another option is outlined here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/72c7f0b51325a209/7300393d9a1c467a - the idea is simply to inform consumers that this content provider's calls need to happen asynchronously, making the asynchronous requirement an application concern rather than a content provider concern.

Comment: `onChange` where?